# WCF REST service bind class with a GET

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, query-string, whatsapp

I am trying to move WhatsApp webhook processing from ASP.NET to a WCF service. The POST interface works but in the initial hand shake when setting up the hook WhatsApp calls the method using

```
GET https://www.your-clever-domain-name.com/webhooks?
  hub.mode=subscribe&
  hub.challenge=1158201444&
  hub.verify_token=meatyhamhock
```

In ASP.NET the method looks like Verify( class hub ) and everything binds as it should.

Moving this to WCF is not so simple.My operations contracts looks like:

```
[OperationContract]
[CLSCompliant(true)]
[WebGet( RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
       , ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json
       , BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
       , UriTemplate ="/WhatsApp/hub.mode/{mode}/hub.challenge/{challenge}/hub.verify_token/{verify_token}")]
String  VerifyToken( string mode, string challenge, string verify_token );
```

Trying to call this from my edge browser:

```
https://service.xxxxxx.com:1234/RemoteService/WhatsApp?mode=xxxx&challenge=yyyyy&verify_token=zzzz

https://service.xxxxxx.com:1234/RemoteService/WhatsApp?hub.mode=xxxx&hub.challenge=yyyyy&hub.verify_token=zzzz
```

I get in either case:

```
Method not allowed. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.
```

I do not controll of how I am being called so I need to be able handle that exact GET format.

I am sure my UriTemplate for is not correct, or can this even be done?
####################################################################
Working through this I have replaced the method definition to:

```
[OperationContract]
[CLSCompliant(true)]
[WebGet]
String  WhatsApp( string mode, string challenge, string verify_token );
```

I can get control to the method but the parameters are not mapped. So there should be a way to get the QueryString parameters, which contain periods, into a c# variable. Mapping hub.mode to just mode would be great.

==============================================================
By changing my method to:

```
public String  WhatsApp( string mode, string challenge, string verify_token )
{
    var par = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters;
    mode         = par["hub.mode"];
    challenge    = par["hub.challenge"];
    verify_token = par["hub.verify_token"];
    
    return challenge;
}
```

I can now get the parameters, but this is really tacky, there has got to be a better way.

Comment: A HTTP Request can be a GET with not body or a POST with a body.  Not sure but you have a GET with a BODY.

Comment: Try **UriTemplate ="/WhatsApp/{*querystring}")**.

Comment: However, your error seems to be a 405 error. I wonder if the cause could be because you don't receive get requests.

Comment: Look at the end of my post, that code actually works, so I am getting control. It just looks bad. Functionally I am OK.